# Using form and controls variables in not managed class

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, class, c++-cli, managed-c++

i have a question, how can i use this variables in standart class?
Sample

```
ref class test
{
  Button ^x; 
};
```

works good, but i need not managed class..

and this not work

```
   class test
   {
     Button ^x;
   };
```

maybe anybody have a solution?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this with the help of gcroot like this:

```
class test
{
    gcroot<Button^> *x;
};
```

You can then create this field's object in your constructor like:

```
x = gcnew Button();
```

and generally use x like a Button^...